# Use the Facebook JS API to comment on a webpage that doesn't have a numerical object id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

How can I create a comment, programmatically, if the page doesn't have a numerical Facebook object-id?

I have a webpage with a custom made commenting system. When somebody comments on it, I want the comment to also post to Facebook, along the lines of:

```
[Person A] posted a comment on [Title of Page, also links to page]
This is the comment that the person wrote...
```

In the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-comments/#creating), it says to do the following:

```
    POST /{object-id}/comments?
    message='This is my message'
```

My question is: if my page doesn't seem to have an object-id, how can I do this?

I made a call to my site, to get the ID, but it just returns the URL. For example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://myurl.com/

returns:

{
   "http://myurl.com/": {
      "id": "http://myurl.com/"
   }
}
```

So how can I POST with my object-id if there is no numerical object-id?  What can I do to create new comments against a page that doesn't have a numerical object-id, according to Facebook?

Extra info:

In the HEAD of the page I define it with Facebook meta tags of type "article".

```
  <meta property="og:type"   content="article" />
```

Comment: Do you want to post the comment on the user's timeline or on your application Facebook page?

Answer (score 2):

See, a comment is a reply to a feed/post. So in your case, you don't need to comment, you simply want to post a feed to your page something like:

> [Person A] posted a comment on [Title of Page, also links to page]
>   This is the comment that the person wrote...

For this, simply use:

`\POST` `/PAGE_ID/feed?message=MESSAGE`

(You can see the available parameters list of feed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/))

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the cleanest way to achieve this is using opengraph actions.
First, if you don't have one (I do hope you have one), create a FB app, and use Facebook Connect to authentify your users and obtain an access_token, with the permission to 'publish_actions'

Then you create 1 opengraph object: one webpage object (this is you webpage with opengraph meta elements like the one you showed us).
After that, you'll be able to create a "post a comment" action, related to the webpage object.

Look at the opengraph documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ and 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started/

Comment: Agree, OpenGraph is not the quickest and easiest solution but the result will be much better regarding the expected result shown in the original question. But even with OpenGraph he needs the object-id

Comment: well not exactly. He just need to have all the required opengraph metadata in the webpage to be considered as a webpage object by facebook. Then when he will 'post' his action, he will have to provide the url of the 'object' i.e. the webpage, and facebook will do the rest.

What he can also do is to provide directly the opengraph elements by json, like I explained in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341888/posting-a-custom-story-to-facebook-open-graph/18359854#comment26970839_18359854

Comment: Yes this is a good improvement, but even wit this that doesn't solve his problem

Comment: why not? with this, and user's permission, he's able to do exactly what he asked for: publish an action on user's feed telling he had just commented a specific webpage, with the content of the comment